# SharePoint 2010, Upload Document Redirect to Page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, document

I have a document library in SharePoint 2010 that several different teams are using for the same purpose.  Each team has their own page that has a filtered view of the document library on it.  The document library also has custom columns.

The issue I am running into is when a team member uploads a document from their page.  They click "Add document" from their page, and then they browse to the document they want to upload.  This part works perfectly - and the URL specifies the source as the team's page.  However, after a user selects the document and clicks "OK", it takes them to the EditForm.aspx page that allows the user to fill in the meta data for the document. This is fine, but now the source URL specifies a view from inside of the document library, and no longer points to the team's page (where they came from).

Does anyone know how I can change this source URL to point to the team's page instead of the document library?  Or, does anyone know a workaround for this issue so that a user can upload a document from a page (with document library web part on it) so that it returns to the page?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 should work the way you want out-of-the-box.  I tried to reproduce your situation, but was unable to.  What I did was set up a library with one custom column and two custom views.  I then created two pages, one with a list form web part using one view and one with a list form web part with the other view.

When I click on the Add Document from either page, a modal dialog window opens to the Upload page.   I first select the file (Upload.aspx) and then am redirected to the metadata properties (EditForm.aspx).  After filling out the metadata, the dialog window closes, and the page behind it (the page we were originally on) refreshes to show the new document in the web part.  So the user experience is that they stay on the page they want while adding the document as desired.

If you edit your question or provide comments with more details on your situation we can try to reproduce it, but the functionality you describe is exactly how it is supposed to work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Peter's correct - SharePoint's being SharePoint.

If I am reading this right, it may be that you should simply check out in-line editing. Using a view, you and edit the properties dynamically without leaving the page (each team getting their own view).

Alternately, I see many who simply want to redirect users back to the page they came from either edit or view of an item regardless of where that was (a link, etc.). Simplest way to do that is a little programming by adding a button to the forms replacing the OK/Cancel with your own code. Simply edit the forms using InfoPath to add the new buttons - you have the user context if you need to custom redirect to a team home page or some such.